# Setting Exec-Path When Using Zsh and Tmux

Tags: init-file, path, exec-path, zsh

I am using Emacs 25.2 with Zsh; and I have added the following to my init.el file to set both the *Path* and *exec-path*.

```
;; Set shell path
(defun set-shell-path ()
  (let ((shell-path (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -i -c 'echo $PATH'")))
    (setenv "PATH" shell-path)
    (setq exec-path (split-string shell-path path-separator))))

(when (display-graphic-p)
    (set-shell-path))
```

When the above executes it results in the error:

> ("compaudit" "133" "command not found" "getent compaudit" "open terminal failed" ...)

My *zshrc* includes the following:

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit -i
...
# Launch Tmux.
if command -v tmux &> /dev/null; then
  [[ ! $TERM =~ dumb ]] && [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [ -z $TMUX ] && exec tmux -u
fi
...
```

Suggestions on how I can/should solve this error are appreciated? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever `compinit` is, apparently it fails if there's no terminal. Since you're running this shell command inside emacs, there's not going to be a terminal.

Also, `exec-path` is already initialized from your `PATH` when emacs starts up; none of this should be necessary.